# topojson.feature with topojson v2

Tags: node.js, d3.js, geojson, topojson, topojson2

I've been following the "let's make a map" tutorial https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/, however in the middle of the tutorial, drawing the paths failed with errors about topojson.feature() is not a function.

script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: topojson.feature is not a function(…)
(anonymous function) @ script.js:14
(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:6
call @ d3.min.js:6
e @ d3.min.js:6

script.js:

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

d3.json("js/uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(uk);
  
  svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits))
  .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
});
```

HTML included scripts:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Map test</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
      <script src='js/d3.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src='js/topojson.js'></script>
      <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Originally I've suspected the issue to be with the topojson file I've converted Pathfile-GeoJSON-TopoJSON, I've names it uk.js for testing purposes while following the tutorial.
Another hint as mentioned in the reply here:
https://github.com/topojson/topojson/issues/236
However after changing the issue remained the same, and confirmed after substituting uk.json I've creted myself with:
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the topojson client files, which have been split off from the base topojson code in v2. If you include the following script in your code, it should work:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@2"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise, the error disappeared although resulted in another error complaining about "path" not being defined, after some experimentation, adding:  


var subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits);


Before the d3 call fixed the "path undefined" error, but starts complaining about uk not being defined.

Are these errors also caused by the changes in topojson v2 ?
Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Comment: Are you using d3 v4? There were some API changes in v4 such as `d3.geo.path` now being `d3.geoPath`. `uk` not being defined should only be an issue if your `d3.json` call is failing to load it. Can you update your question's code with your new code?

Comment: Yes, the version I'm using currently is 4.4.0
For better format, I've uploaded the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/syj4jhes/11/

Comment: You're attempting to access the `uk` object before it has been loaded. Move the `var subunit = ...` line of code inside of the `d3.json` callback function.

Comment: Thank you once again, after checking https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md I see the command changes.